# multiple sortable lists using jqueryui - don't want items to mix between list groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two pairs of drag/drop/sortable lists using JqueryUI.http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

My problem is that I can move items from sortable1, sortable2 into sortable3 and 4. I want them to be debated. So items can only move between ( 1 and 2 ) and (3 and 4).

Do I have to assign a different class to sortable3 and sortable4 for this to happen? Is there anyway I can somehow combine the function?

```
$(function() {
        $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
            connectWith: "ul"
        });

        $( "ul.dropfalse" ).sortable({
            connectWith: "ul",
            dropOnEmpty: false
        });

        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).disableSelection();
        $( "#sortable3, #sortable4").disableSelection();

});


<ul id="sortable1" class='droptrue'>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Can be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class='dropfalse'>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Cannot be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable3" class='droptrue'>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Can be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable4" class='dropfalse'>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Cannot be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See my additional edit to answer your question in your comment about adding #sortable5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of your `droptrue` and `dropfalse` parameters, and the fact that you have unique id's on each list, you don't need to change the markup, you just need to call the `.sortable` function a bit differently:

```
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable2"
    });

    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable1",
        dropOnEmpty: false
    });

    $( "#sortable3" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable4",
    });

    $( "#sortable4" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable3",
        dropOnEmpty: false
    });
```

Alternatively, you could use an object to set up the parameters of each sortable item, and iterate through the object, using the parameters to apply `.sortable` to each:

```
var lists = [{"listid":"#sortable1", "connectid":"#sortable2", "drop":true},
 {"listid":"#sortable2", "connectid":"#sortable1", "drop":false},
 {"listid":"#sortable3", "connectid":"#sortable4", "drop":true},
 {"listid":"#sortable4", "connectid":"#sortable3", "drop":false}];

$.each(lists, function(i, list) {
    $(list.listid).sortable({
        connectWith: list.connectid,
        dropOnEmpty: list.drop
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment, this is how you could tie in yet another list (`#sortable5`, connecting to both `#sortable3` and `#sortable4`).  **Note the use of multiple id's, separated by commas**:

```
var lists = [{"listid":"#sortable1", "connectid":"#sortable2", "drop":true},
 {"listid":"#sortable2", "connectid":"#sortable1", "drop":false},
 {"listid":"#sortable3", "connectid":"#sortable4, #sortable5", "drop":true},
 {"listid":"#sortable4", "connectid":"#sortable3, #sortable5", "drop":false},
 {"listid":"#sortable5", "connectid":"#sortable3, #sortable4", "drop":false}];
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the reply. But what if I had another list sortable5, which connected to both 3 and 4 but not 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for posting and then answering this.  I had a similar challenge, and your answers gave me the inspiration I needed to solve it.  I too have multiple sortable lists and  don't want to mix between sort groups.  In my case the number of groups is dependant on the data, so I don't know how many I will have. Here is the solution I came up with.

```
$(function() {    
  if ($.cookie("sortGroupsCnt")) {
      var grpcnt = Number($.cookie("sortGroupsCnt"));        
      for (i = 0; i < grpcnt; i++) { 
          var connectClass = ".s" + i;  
          $(connectClass).sortable({
              connectWith: connectClass,
              dropOnEmpty: true
          }).disableSelection(); 
      }
  };
```

});

In my PHP logic, Within each sort group I create multiple UL's all with the same class code.  So in group 1 all UL's have class="s0".  In group 2 all UL's have class="s1", etc. Then I create a cookie called "sortGroupCnt" which is the number of sort groups created.

Thanks again everyone.